# Understanding Cloud SQL Instance `duration` value in the logs (Postgres)

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, latency

I have `Cloud SQL Postgres` for my database. I ran the script on the Master Instance, I ran  `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` on the query say

```
(SELECT * FROM "Customers" WHERE "userId"='<random_string>')
```

and then ran the raw query (i.e. without `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`).

`EXPLAIN ANALYZE` showed that it will complete the execution in `1.5 ms` but in the `Cloud SQL` logs I found that the query will take `1600 ms`.

I also did the same (`EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and raw query) with `SELECT 1`, postgres reported Execution time of 0.01 ms but `Cloud SQL` logs showed `150 ms`.

So, I wanted to understand why is there so much difference between the two execution time?
the `duration` value in the logs is not calculated by `Postgres`? it is calculated by `Cloud SQL`? If yes then what are the possible other things that could take time?

I tried searching online and in GCP docs the internals of `Cloud SQL` but couldn't find much info.

Comment: @nbk I was not able to understand what you said.

Comment: you get a result from explain / analyze, so please post it in your question